# Counting words in a text file, C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to count the number of words in a text file. My code seems correct but whenever I run the code, the word and line count seems to be a very large random number.

My file test.txt only has a couple words in a couple lines.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string INPUT_FILE = "test.txt";
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(INPUT_FILE);
 
    string line;
    int numlines;
    int numWords;
    
    while(getline(inFile, line))
    {
        numlines++;
        
        stringstream lineStream(line);
        while(getline(lineStream, line, ' '))
        {
            numWords++;
        }
        
    }

    inFile.close();
    
    cout<<"line count = "<< numlines<<endl;
    cout<<"word count = "<< numWords<<endl;
}
```

Comment: The stream extractor operator `>>` reads space-delimited "words", why not use it?

Comment: Also you need to initialize your variables. Uninitialized local variables really are uninitialized, and will have indeterminate (seemingly random or garbage) values. Using them without initialization will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int numlines;
int numWords;
```

These variables are declared and defined but not initialized. As such this is undefined behavior, manifesting itself as initial values of these counters being random garbage.

In this case you must explicitly set them to 0, here.

Comment: Drinking gin&tonic until 2 AM tends to make me a little bit picky... :P Any way, you got my upvote

Comment: Try red wine, instead. Loosens things up quite well.

Comment: Drank all of  that last weekend!

Comment: Why did you stop?

Comment: Besides drinking it all? Well I do have to work during the weeks, and even with the office closed (again!) working and alcohol is not usually a great combination.  Beside the wife and kids might not appreciate it as much as I would.